# for + period of time

Tags: prepositions, time

> You should write one hour every day.

or

> You should write **for** one hour every day.

Which one of the above sentences is correct? 
Can someone please help me understand when do we have to use **for** when talking about time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express a duration of time, you use **for**.

> You should write **for** one hour every day.

You could also use the other option, omitting for, but the meaning may not always be clear in all contexts.

You could omit for in a situation such as:

> **You should jog 5 hours a day.**

When using a sentence such as: You should write one hour every day, it sounds more idiomatic to say **You should write an hour a day.**

**a day** or **per day** can be used in place of every day.